# What's the auditory equivalent of seeing at a glance and smelling in a whiff?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm thinking of something like listening/recognizing at a beat/heartbeat.

Comment: Is 'smelling in a whiff' ever used? I've only come across metaphorical uses of 'in a whiff', like 'We got there in a whiff'.

Comment: Your ears prick up.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't know about the explicit verb *smelling* but that’s certainly what *to catch a whiff of* means.

Comment: You might catch a snatch of conversation or a phrase

Comment: I can [name that tune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_That_Tune) in *N* notes.     :-)     ⁠

Comment: @tchrist According to [Collins Cobuild ABED](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/at-a-glance) (whence the second quote), [CDAI](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/at+a+glance) and (first quote) [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/glance), 'at a glance' means << _immediately upon looking_ :
she saw at a glance what had happened.>> //<< If you see something at a glance, you see or recognize it immediately, and without having to think or look carefully. ⇒ One could tell at a glance that she was a compassionate person.>> 'Catch a whiff of' ...

Comment: doesn't have the same sense of complete understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, ***catching a whisper***.

From dictionary.cambridge.org:

> **[catch](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/catch)** *verb* (HEAR/SEE)
>
> [ T ] to manage to hear something:
>
> I couldn't catch what the announcer said, with all the other noise
> going on.
>
> **[whisper](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/whisper)** *noun* (SPEECH)
>
> [ C ] a way of speaking very quietly, using the breath but not the
> voice, so that only the person close to you can hear you:
>
> I heard whispers outside my room.
>
> She said it in a whisper so I presumed it wasn't common knowledge.
> "You see," she said, lowering her voice to a whisper, "he hasn't been
> well recently." ​
>
> [ S ] *literary* **a soft, low noise**:
>
> The silence was broken only by the whisper of the leaves in the gentle
> breeze.

Refer to [examples in Google News Search](https://www.google.com/#tbm=nws&q=%22catch+a+whisper%22), and [these in Google Books Search](https://www.google.com/#q=%22catch+a+whisper%22&tbm=bks).

Answer (score -2):

How about "to catch the sound of"?

Comment: This doesn't carry the sense of (immediate) recognition. It corresponds to 'catch sight of' / 'catch a whiff of'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't understand. alwayslearning answer, *catch a whisper* has two upvotes, while this one has two downvotes. Why? We do not *whisper* with our ears, but our ears can *catch* hold of a sound or word.

Comment: @Bluewoman Democracy is the worst possible form of regulation. Apart from all the others. Voting often seems inexplicable. Some swr's get more upvotes than something a certain professor spent months researching. FWIW, I didn't downvote your answer (as you're quite new here), but the 'in a trice' overlap with 'at a glance' isn't reflected in your answer either.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thank you for replying. I'm quite happy with the downvotes for my answer, which isn't parallel to  *see—glance*. I thought the expression "within earshot" was maybe useful for others to know.